# Puppet HTTP 400 error With Environment Configuration

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have reconfigured my puppet (v3.6.2) server (RHEL 7.1) into supporting environments as shown below.

```
/etc/puppet
           puppet.conf
           auth.conf
           environments
                       Project_A
                                modules
                                manifests/site.pp
                                environment.conf
                       Project_B
                                modules
                                manifests/site.pp
                                environment.conf
```

the environment.conf files consist of

```
modulepath=/etc/puppet/environments/$environment/modules
manifest=/etc/puppet/environments/$environment/manifests/site.pp
```

the site.pp file for each environment consists of

```
include 'nodes.pp'
include 'selinux.pp'
include 'check_mode.pp'
$puppetserver=<SERVER>
Package {
        allow_virtual=>true,
}
```

on an agent when I run the command

```
puppet agent --no-daemonize --trace --debug --noop --verbose
```

I get the error

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on server: Could not find class nodes for <'SERVER'> on <'SERVER'>

in /var/log/puppet/masterhttp.log i get the error

> [2015-09-09 15:43:12] <'IP'> - - [2015/09/09:15:43:12 AEST] "POST /Project_A/catalog/<'SERVER'> HTTP/1.1 400 21

Each agent has the same configuration as when puppet had a single environment with the addition of 'environment = 'PROJECT_A'

If I change nodes.pp in site.pp from include to import
import 'nodes.pp'
the error changes to

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on server: Could not find class selinux.pp for <'SERVER'> on <'SERVER'>

This same structure work correctly when puppet was configured for a single environment.
Under the single environment everything was configured as such:

```
/etc/puppet
           puppet.conf
           auth.conf
           environments
           modules
           manifests/site.pp
```

I suspect that I may need to modify my auth.conf file but am at a loss as to what changes are required. Currently the file is the default configuration.

I have tried adding

```
path /environments
allow *
```

with no joy

and have added to fileserver.conf

```
path /etc/puppet/environments 
allow *
```

again with no joy.

for the record the master puppet.conf file is

```
[main]
      logdir = /var/log/puppet
      rundir = /var/run/puppet
      ssldir = $vardir/ssl
      always_cache_features = true
      server = <'PUPPET SERVER'>
      environmentpath = $confdir/environments

[master]
      ca = true
      dns_alt_names = <'SAN DNS ENTRIES'>
      certname = <'PUPPET MASTER'>
      ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
      ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
      environment = master
[agent]
      classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
      localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
      environment = Project_A
```

The agents use the same configuration file without the [master]

Can anyone see where I have made a mistake in my configuration.

UPDATE:
I have started the puppetmaster in debug mode and from an agent tried to connect to the server. In the debug output this is what has made me suspect that it is auth.conf

```
Notice: Starting Pppet master version 3.6.2
Debug: Routes Registered
Debug: Route /^\/v2\.0/
Debug: Route /.*/
Debug: Evaluating match for Route /^\/v2\.0/
Debug: Did not match path ("/Project_A/node/<SERVER A>")
Debug: Evaluating match for Route /.*/
Info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[^/catalog/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
Info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[^/node/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
Info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate_revocation_list/ca]: allowing * access
Info: access[/^/report/([^/]+)$]: allowing 'method' save
Info: access[/^/report/([^/]+)$]: allowing $1 access
Info: access[/file]: allowing * access
Info: access[/certificate/ca]: adding authentication any
Info: access[/certificate/ca]: adding 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate/ca]: adding * access
Info: access[/certificate/]: adding authentication any
Info: access[/certificate/]: adding 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate/]: adding * access
Info: access[/certificate_request]: adding authentication any
Info: access[/certificate_request]: adding 'method' find
Info: access[/certificate_request]: adding 'method' save
Info: access[/certificate_request]: adding * access
Info: access[/v2.0/environments]: adding 'method' find
Info: access[/v2.0/environments]: adding * access
Info: access[/]: adding authentication any
Info: Inserting dfault '/status' (auth true) ACL
Info: Caching node for <SERVER A>
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format [msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: node supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml raw
Debug: Routes Register:
Debug: Routes /^\/v2\.0/
Debug: Route /.*/
Debug: Evaluating match for Route /^\/v2\.0/
Debug: Did not match path ("/Project_A/file_metadatas/plugins")
Debug: Evaluating match for Route /.*/
```

UPDATE:
I have sort of got this working.
After rereading the puppetlabs docs on environments it states that there has to be an environment called production. I have thus created

```
/etc/puppet/environments/production
                              | modules
                              | manifests
                              | environment.conf
```

This is configured the same as the other environments although the dirs currently have no files within them.

The agent remains the same.

Now when I run the agent it runs without errors. The only thing is that it is collecting information from the puppet root
/etc/puppet/modules & /etc/puppet/manifests 
and while the agent runs doesn't do anything if the host isn't defined in /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp.

In the puppetmaster debug output all references to the host are defined as Project_A and there is the log entry

> Notice: Compiled catalog for <'SERVER_A'> in environment Project_A in 0.00 seconds

From the agent

```
Notice: /Stage/[main]/ntp::Config/File[/etc/ntp.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}<md5sum>' to '{md5}<md5sum>'
Info: /Stage/[main]/ntp::Config/File[/etc/ntp.conf]: Scheduling refresh of Service{ntpd}
```

So in summary.

The client is being recognised as belonging to environment 'Project_A' on the master. Despite being configured to use the path /etc/puppet/environments/$environment/{modules|manifests/site.pp} in the 'Project_A' environment.conf file.
Is actually using /etc/puppet/{modules|manifests/site.pp}

Comment: I have started the puppetmaster in debug mode and then tried to do an update via the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of those who answered.

This has been resolved.

When implementing environments the following applies

- A default environment of production is required (as per the docs)
- even though it may be configured in puppet.conf when testing via the command line include "--server <'SERVER'> and --environment <'ENVIRONMENT'>"
- Clear the cache located in /var/opt/lib/puppet/client_data/catalog/<'SERVER NAME'>.json

All the way through I was observing weird behaviour that disappeared when the cache was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your directory permissions. The web server may not have access to the directories.

Comment: what is the directory path of your environment "/etc/puppet/environments/Project A" with one space or "/etc/puppet/environments/Project_A" ?

Comment: it is "/etc/puppet/environments/Project_A/" all of the above was hand typed in.

Comment: try with puppet agent  --server=yourpuppetmaster.example.com --test --environment Project_A --debug --noop

Comment: I have been using that command but admit hadn't used it after creating the default 'production' environment. Except for an issue in the site.pp it is now working